# How do I split a column of factors into multiple columns of multiple factors?

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Factor     Value
======     =====
1A.In      1.0
1A.Out     2.6
1B.In      0.5
1B.Out     3.4
2A.In      5.5
```

etc.

My goal is to add columns to the data frame that extract information from the single Factor column, as such:

```
Factor   Value   Fact1     Fact2     Fact3
======   =====   =====     =====     =====
1A.In    1.0     1         A         In  
1A.Out   2.6     1         A         Out
1B.In    0.5     1         B         In
1B.Out   3.4     1         B         Out
2A.In    5.5     2         A         In
```

I just cannot figure out how to do this without using subset ad nauseum. I'm relatively new to R, and don't have a background in programming, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `?substr`.

```
within(df, {
    Fact1 <- substr(Factor, 1, 1)
    Fact2 <- substr(Factor, 2, 2)
    Fact3 <- substr(Factor, 4, 999)
})
```

I'm making assumptions here about how many characters to use for each new variable. For more generality, you should have some kind of regular structure in `Factor`, eg dots as separators for all your variables.

Comment: Nice use of substr, +1

Comment: I'd prefer to do the last one programatically: `substr(Factor, 4, max(nchar(Factor))`. But that's pretty OCD.